# set installer background / not able to run early_command in custom preseed file

Tags: desktop-background, ubiquity, preseed

I have a custom preseed file for a Precise Live CD  (which is well loaded on boot, I checked syslog for that).

My initial problem is that when booting in install mode (default behavior for a Live CD), ubiquity runs X with a default wallpaper which is hardcoded to /usr/share/backgrounds/warty-final-ubuntu.png in Ubiquity code.

So my idea was to run early_command (https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/installation-guide/i386/preseed-advanced.html) to copy my custom wallpaper over /usr/share/backgrounds/warty-final-ubuntu.png.

Assuming my custom wallpaper allready resides on the rootfs in /usr/share/backgrounds.

But... It seems the early_command never runs (and I'm sure the preseed file is taken into account)

Here is what I have added to my preseed file:

```
d-i preseed/early_command string cp /usr/share/backgrounds/mywallpaper-defaults.jpg /usr/share/backgrounds/warty-final-ubuntu.png
```

Even this one is never run:

```
d-i preseed/early_command string /usr/bin/touch /tmp/testearly
```

Thanks for helping !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`preseed/early_command` is run in the initramfs.  If you intend to affect files in the live environment, you need to prefix the filenames with `/root`.

This will not affect the installed system.  If you want that, you're better off changing the squashfs directly.

Comment: Thanks ! My aim is specifically to not affect the installed system nor the squashfs as I don't want to broke ubuntu wallpapers package. I want this change to be a 'volatile workaround' from the running live system fs as I can't do anything else cleaner :/ Note that this problem only affect "install" mode as lightdm is not used (but ubiquity-dm).

Comment: Updated wiki page: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbiquityAutomation