# How to access a file on the boot medium from the live installer preseed/early_command?

Tags: 18.04, system-installation, live-usb, preseed

I'm currently trying to set up a preseed file for my ubuntu desktop 18.04. An easy way to see that it is working would be to change the background image of the ubuntu live installer. So, inspired by [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/155707/set-installer-background-not-able-to-run-early-command-in-custom-preseed-file) I added to the start of my preseeding file:

```
d-i preseed/early_command string cp /cdrom/preseed/warty-final-ubuntu-blue.png /root/usr/share/backgrounds/warty-final-ubuntu.png
```

I added the prefix `/root` to the target path as suggested by [UbiquityAutomation](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbiquityAutomation)

> You can use preseed/early_command with the live CD; it will be run by "casper" (the component which sets up a live environment at boot time) from the initramfs.
>   Please note that, if you want to affect files in the live environment, this means that you must prefix their filenames with /root.

When I boot from my usb stick (which I created with `mkisofs`, `isohybrid` and `dd`) I get to the part where the installer starts verifying. It automatically chooses the language, as I specified that in the boot parameters, and then shows the partitioning dialog (as is expected, I haven't specified partitioning in the preseed file). But the background remains the same.

When I open tty2 by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd> and log in with ubuntu, I can see in `/log/var/casper.log` that cp failed to stat my file.

But I can see the file at this time. It's there under `/cdrom/preseed/warty-final-ubuntu-blue.png` just as I expected it to be. Of course, the `preseed/early_command` is run by casper and hence might not have the same filesystem accessible as I have during the installation. But if that were the case, it would be weird that it does actually execute the `cp` command from my preseed file, which is located at `/cdrom/preseed/early_command`. In the boot arguments, it is specified with that path.

How can I copy my image file from the usb stick over to the live system?
I am explicitly asking about the live system, not the target system that is being installed.

Comment: If you are booting a Live CD or USB the files on it are located in the folder **cdrom** they are usually read only, If you are booting a ISO file, the files on it are found in the folder **isodevice**. They are also usually read only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if you want to affect files in the live environment, [...] you must prefix their filenames with `/root`.

I knew that in the live environment I can access the usb stick's file system with `/cdrom`. So I tried whether using `/root/cdrom` might work, and it does indeed work.

```
d-i preseed/early_command string cp /root/cdrom/preseed/warty-final-ubuntu-blue.png /root/usr/share/backgrounds/warty-final-ubuntu.png
```

Comment: Answers that can explain why this is the case are still appreciated